# How does Leaflet download tiles?

Tags: leaflet

I've checked the [source of Leaflet](http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet-src.js) and have not found any usage of `XMLHttpRequest`. How does it download tiles from remote HTTP servers? What mechanism does it use? Where is it in the source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaflet creates img element in the document with the url of the tile as a source.

It happends here: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/tile/TileLayer.js#L60